# "Elle s'est faite mal" or "Elle s'est fait mal"?

Tags: grammaire

What is the grammatical function of "*se*" here? Is it a COD ou COI? 
Which one is correct?

> elle s'est faite mal.

ou

> elle s'est fait mal.

Answer (score 5):

It is a COI: the phrase means literally "elle a fait mal à elle-même".

The correct form is therefore *elle s'est fait mal*.

Comment: Note that you would write: *Elle s'est faite mâle.* (She turns herself into a male)

Comment: @jlliagre  *Elle s'est faite* [pause] *mal*. A native would probably not write it, but we can imagine it in oral speech when hesitating, possibly accompanied by an interpolated clause.

Comment: @None Yes, that's a case where it might happen: *Elle s'est faite [toute seule, mais] mal*.

Comment: @jjlliagre
 Elle s'est fait mal à qui à "s'" donc à elle donc oui, "Elle s'est faite toute seule". Très juste.

Answer (score 0):

Here, **both sentences are correct in French**. Although they are similar, they don't mean the same thing.

> Elle s'est faite mal

Would mean that *she made herself wrong* rather than *she hurt herself*, which is the correct meaning for the second sentence.

Though the first sentence is logically eccentic (as someone cannot make himself wrong?), it is French-speaking correct. However, to be honest, we would rather say *elle s'est mal faite* if we want it to be 100% correct.

Comment: *Elle s'est faite mal* is quite unidiomatic. We'd rather say: *elle s'est mal faite* .

Comment: @jlliagre I agree about it not being idiomatic French but it could be heard and quite understandable. I except with the proper context and intonation we might find an example where it could fit.

Comment: I agree @jlliagre! Edited my answer to specify it.